Fatal error C1083 only when using Visual Studio 2022 with CMAKE
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I am completely confused. The project is CMAKE based and builds fine on the command line and in Visual Studio 2019. But in vs2022 it will not build with either Visual Studio 17 2022 or Visual Studio 16 2019 selected as a compiler.
The error is always:
Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Eigen/Dense': No such file or directory exists. 

This is a minimal example I created to test my sanity.
test.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
 
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TEST)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(EIGEN3 REQUIRED)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME}
    test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen)

CMakePresets.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
      "major": 3,
      "minor": 25,
      "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
      {
          "name": "windows-vs22",
          "displayName": "Windows x64 Release",
          "description": "Default Windows CMake preset",
          "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
          "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
          "architecture": {
              "value": "x64",
              "strategy": "external"
          },
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
          "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH": "${sourceDir}/conan/install/Release",
          "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "${sourceDir}/conan/install/Release"

        },
          "vendor": {
              "microsoft.com/VisualStudioSettings/CMake/1.0": {
                  "hostOS": [
                      "Windows"
                  ]
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "name": "windows-vs19",
          "displayName": "Windows x64 Release",
          "description": "Default Windows CMake preset",
          "generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019",
          "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
          "architecture": {
              "value": "x64",
              "strategy": "external"
          },
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
          "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH": "${sourceDir}/conan/install/Release",
          "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "${sourceDir}/conan/install/Release"

        },
          "vendor": {
              "microsoft.com/VisualStudioSettings/CMake/1.0": {
                  "hostOS": [
                      "Windows"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
      {
          "name": "windows-vs22",
          "displayName": "Release",
          "configurePreset": "windows-vs22"
      },
      {
          "name": "windows-vs19",
          "displayName": "Release",
          "configurePreset": "windows-vs19"
      }
  ]
}

Is Visual Studio 2022 with CMake just bugged, or what does I do wrong?
I'm confused since the project files seem to be fine because why should it even build on command line and in vs2019?
Does anyone have any clue for me?
EDIT 1 - The cmake log inside visual studio 2022 (when configuring 2019):
Working directory: C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/mini_eigen/build/windows-vs19
1> [CMake] -- CMake Version: 3.29.5-msvc4
1> [CMake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Conan: Component target declared 'Eigen3::Eigen'
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done (4.6s)
1> [CMake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/mini_eigen/build/windows-vs19
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted toolchain configurations.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> CMake generation finished.


Pretty sure you should have a target_include_directories in your cmakelists.txt file. That's the normal way that you tell cmake to tell the compiler where to find header files.

@john: There is find_package(Eigen3) and target_link_libraries (... Eigen3::Eigen) calls in the project. Normally they are sufficient to add Eigen include directories.

@john but I assume that the Eigen3Config.cmake file downloaded by conan and then called by find_package() should handle this. Especially since it works in vs2019 and on the command line...

Note: The correct name of Eigen package for search with find_package is Eigen3. The name EIGEN3 is incorrect, while it may work on case-insensitive filesystems.

In the configuration log Conan reports that it declares target Eigen3::Eigen. It looks like the problem is on the Conan side. Or its package installation is somehow corrupted. If you want to debug that problem, you could start with inspection the exact parameters passed to the compiler. Among those parameters find the one denoted Eigen include directory. Then check whether given directory actually has Eigen/ subdirectory and Dense file in that subdirectory.

@Tsyvarev: But why does this minimal example work on the command line or in Visual Studio 2019 without changing anything in the files? I also tested Clion, just for fun, and who would have guessed it, it just works out of the box with the same minimal example. So I guess Visual Studio is just buggy or Microsoft does not want users to use cmake instead of their solution stuff.

"So I guess Visual Studio is just buggy or Microsoft does not want users to use cmake instead of their solution stuff." - Or it could be that CMake is bugged, or Conan. Or it could be that you have configured your Visual Studio in a wrong way. These are only guesses. All of them have a little value until you will debug the problem.

Found the root problem:
Inside the TEST.vcxproj file inside the build folder the line:
<AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions) /external:I "C:/Users/USERNAME/.conan2/p/eigencc87d85134e3d/p/include/eigen3"</AdditionalOptions> is missing when configuring with vs2022. The other approaches generate this project file with this line. When this line is added manually after configure is done, it works as expected.  So this missing line leads to all my issues with vs2022.
I tested the newested cmake version, by setting it in vs2022, but this  does not fix this problem.

I fixed it by adding the following to the CMakeLists.txt file
if (CMAKE_VERSION MATCHES "-msvc")
    include_directories(${Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

So now when the project is built from within the Visual Studio UI, the Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIR is extra included so that Visual Studio will work. Why this is necessary in VS2022 and not in VS2019 is still a mystery to me.
